# Can't run program in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, base64

My program runs fine in the IDLE, but I get this error every time I run it in the terminal, why? This is my code below an a picture of the error, don't worry it is saved ignore the stars.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You are trying to invoke python to invoke the file _from the Python REPL_.  You need to be calling `python Base64.py` from your operating system's shell, not from the Python REPL.

Comment: From the terminal font, I'm going to guess you're using Windows. If `python` is in the `%PATH%`, open a command line prompt and just type `python Base64.py` from the directory where that file resides.

Comment: I see, it works from the command prompt but if I double click on the .py file it pops up for a second shows an error and closes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are inside a python shell.  you can't invoke *another* interpreter like you are attempting.

Try from a regular terminal prompt.

Comment: I see, it works from the command prompt but if I double click on the .py file it pops up for a second shows an error and closes?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of typing `python` into the terminal and then typing `python Base64.py` into the python interpreter, just type `python Base64.py` directly into the terminal.